# setting up Session Timeout PHP

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, logout, session-timeout

I'm still new in PHP language. I would like to set Session Timeout to ensure that when user log in to their account, it will limit to few minutes / 1 hour before the account got logout automatically when user log in too long. I refered to this link

> http://bytes.com/topic/php/insights/889606-setting-timeout-php-sessions

while setting up. I might be unsure on how it works whether I've placed the code correctly. But i hope someone would guide me through this question.

I test out by just placing session timeout in one of the page. The session ends in 1 minute.

**coupon.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
$timeout = 60; // Number of seconds until it times out.

// Check if the timeout field exists.
if(isset($_SESSION['timeout'])) {
    // See if the number of seconds since the last
    // visit is larger than the timeout period.
    $duration = time() - (int)$_SESSION['timeout'];
    if($duration > $timeout) {
        // Destroy the session and restart it.
        session_destroy();
        session_start();
    }
}

// Update the timeout field with the current time.
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
?>
```

**sessionTimeout.php**

```
<?php
/***
 * Starts a session with a specific timeout and a specific GC probability.
 * @param int $timeout The number of seconds until it should time out.
 * @param int $probability The probablity, in int percentage, that the garbage 
 *        collection routine will be triggered right now.
 * @param strint $cookie_domain The domain path for the cookie.
 */
function session_start_timeout($timeout=5, $probability=100, $cookie_domain='/') {
    // Set the max lifetime
    ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", $timeout);

    // Set the session cookie to timout
    ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime", $timeout);

    // Change the save path. Sessions stored in teh same path
    // all share the same lifetime; the lowest lifetime will be
    // used for all. Therefore, for this to work, the session
    // must be stored in a directory where only sessions sharing
    // it's lifetime are. Best to just dynamically create on.
    $seperator = strstr(strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)), "WIN") ? "\\" : "/";
    $path = ini_get("session.save_path") . $seperator . "session_" . $timeout . "sec";
    if(!file_exists($path)) {
        if(!mkdir($path, 600)) {
            trigger_error("Failed to create session save path directory '$path'. Check permissions.", E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }
    ini_set("session.save_path", $path);

    // Set the chance to trigger the garbage collection.
    ini_set("session.gc_probability", $probability);
    ini_set("session.gc_divisor", 100); // Should always be 100

    // Start the session!
    session_start_timeout(60, 10);

    // Renew the time left until this session times out.
    // If you skip this, the session will time out based
    // on the time when it was created, rather than when
    // it was last used.
    if(isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
        setcookie(session_name(), $_COOKIE[session_name()], time() + $timeout, $cookie_domain);
    }
}

?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{ 
  session_start(); 
}

$timeout = $_SERVER[‘REQUEST_TIME’];
/**
 * for a 1 minute timeout, specified in seconds
*/
$timeout_duration = 60;

/**
 * Here we look for the user’s LAST_ACTIVITY timestamp. If
 * it’s set and indicates our $timeout_duration has passed,
 * blow away any previous $_SESSION data and start a new one.
 */
if (isset($_SESSION[‘LAST_ACTIVITY’]) && ($timeout - $_SESSION[‘LAST_ACTIVITY’]) > $timeout_duration) {
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    session_start();
}

/**
 * Finally, update LAST_ACTIVITY so that our timeout
 * is based on it and not the user’s login time.
 */
$_SESSION[‘LAST_ACTIVITY’] = $timeout;
?>
```

Comment: Why are you using *smart* quotes?

Comment: what do you mean? @Script47

Comment: Check @Fred-ii-'s answer below.

Comment: stop programming in ms word

Answer (score 2):

You have a whole bunch of funky quotes in your code and that will cause it to fail.

I.e.:

```
$_SERVER[‘REQUEST_TIME’];
         ^            ^
```

those should be regular/standard quotes.

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
```

Make those changes to the rest of those.

Using error reporting would have signaled notices.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

You can easily find and replace those in one go in a code editor or even Notepad with CTRL-H

Comment: Arggggggggg pirate fred knows all

Comment: *Arrrrrr matey!* @Dagon

Comment: *You forgot one very important thing mate, I'm Captain Jack Sparrow.*

Comment: Seems like the gang's all here ;-) (The James Gang)

Comment: @Dagon my speakers were on full and it scared the bejeezus out of me! xD

Comment: @Script47 you have to watch all TEN hours

Comment: @Dagon Ha! 3:30 AM here I'll be off to bed soon, maybe tomorrow.

Comment: Yeah, @Dagon and me will take care of some business on the high seas somewhere. Couple 'o chickies waiting for us on an island. Now to remember which one it was.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Tortuga? :P

Comment: @Script47 Maybe a shot of that rum might make me remember.

Comment: my session should be working after i change the whole bunch of funky quotes to standard one? @Fred-ii-

Comment: what's going on here? haha @Fred-ii- , Script47,  Dagon

Comment: @SitiNurainiYakob Theoretically and if you've followed all instructions to a "T", yes. Try it.

Comment: @SitiNurainiYakob those bums?! lol (joke, joke) ah... they're ok. They're with me. They keep my "six" in check.

Comment: what you mean my followed all instructions to a "T" ? @Fred-ii-

Comment: @SitiNurainiYakob to a "T" means if you followed them completely as per instructions.

Comment: sorry @SitiNurainiYakob to much rum, its gone to my head

Comment: @SitiNurainiYakob I'll have a look at it tomorrow. It's past midnight here and I'm going to bed soon. But by "didn't work", can you elaborate on that? Are you getting errors? If you're not checking for them, use error reporting to catch and display them. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and apply it to all your pages.

Comment: i not quite understand on how this error reporting means. it didn't work such that after i change the funky quotes, my sessions didn't give any timeout. Did i missed out any code? @Fred-ii-

Comment: @SitiNurainiYakob add `error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1);` at the top of all your PHP files, immediately after your opening `<?php` tag. If you see notices/warnings then let me know what they are.

Comment: there's 3 errors. but one of it is  **A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()** @Fred-ii-

Comment: @SitiNurainiYakob in coupon.php you have 2x `session_start();` remove the one in `session_destroy();
        session_start();` and keep only 1 copy inside all files using sessions and at the top under your opening `<?php` tag. But not in sessionTimeout.php

Comment: do you mind giving me a reliable clear example (Step-by-step) on how to set up session timeout that i can refer to? @Fred-ii-

Comment: Talk about the long haul ey.